# Java hide JFrame that is being extended by a class with the click of a button

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionevent

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Choose extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public Choose() {
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    LoginButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Create = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Family Entertainment Center");

    LoginButton.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    LoginButton.setText("Login");
    LoginButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            LoginButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    Create.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    Create.setText("Create Account");
    Create.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            CreateActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(34, 34, 34)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(Create, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 327, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(LoginButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 327, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(39, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(68, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(Create, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 52, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(49, 49, 49)
            .addComponent(LoginButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 52, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(79, 79, 79))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

public static void CreateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JFrame frame = new CreateLogin();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}                                        

public static void LoginButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JFrame frame = new LoginFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

In the Action event listener above I want to hide this jframe while it creates 
the other jFrames. I have tried to instantiate and hide the jframe but that creates a new instance. I have also tried the "this.setVisible(false)" which also doesnt work.

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Metal look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Metal".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Choose.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Choose.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Choose.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Choose.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Choose().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
public static javax.swing.JButton LoginButton;
public static javax.swing.JButton Create;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but if you don't [need them static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods), it should work to remove the `static` field from your `CreateActionPerformed()` and `LoginButtonActionPerformed()` methods. You can then call `setVisible(false)`, because you're now calling from within your `Choose` instance.

```
public void CreateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFrame frame = new CreateLogin();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    setVisible(false);
}
```

You should be able to remove `static` from your `JButtons` as well.

Hope this helps. :)

**Edit:** See comment from Andrew.